# Update ListBox 2 from selection in Listbox1

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with a listbox1 filled with several different customers. I also have several worksheets listed with each one titled after each customers ID number.

each time i click on a customer in listbox1, using the listbox1.list index (customer ID) and the on_click event, activates the corresponding worksheet.

Then data from the active worksheet populates listbox2.

the code i currently have works, AS LONG AS there is data in the worksheet. The worksheets hold data from the corresponding customers orders.

The issue i am having is, if I don't yet have any order history on a customer, i get an error code. If there is no data in a worksheet, i want listbox2 to just show as a blank list box. If i have data in a worksheet then i want that data to show. If i get an order from a customer that i don't yet have data on, and I get this error message, then I will not be able to enter an order. I hope this makes sense and I hope someone can help. I am listing the current code that I am using:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
        'highlighting customer to see quote/order history in listbox2

Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets(ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)).Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True

            'list box2 showing values
Dim lr As Long
lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<----- pulling data from active 
sheet
With ListBox2
.ColumnCount = 3
.ColumnWidths = "70;80;80" '<----- Change to desired column widths
.List = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `If` statement...

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value = "" Then
  ' do you want to clear it here?
  ' .Clear 
Else
  .List = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
End If
```